# Interrupt main python thread from a network listener thread

Tags: python, multithreading, arduino, interrupt, robotics

- I need to interrupt a main thread from another thread in python.
- The desired behavior would be of an exception thrown during the
  execution of the main thread.

**Details:**

The main thread orchestrates an animatronic robot through various threads using queues (voice, motor control, visual animation).

The communication thread listens to an Arduino through USB (listening for movement confirmations).
The Arduino is programmed to handle a button press hardware interrupt by sending a message through the USB connection.

I need to be able to interrupt the main thread's animation routine **as soon** as the hardware interrupt message is received on the communication thread, essentially translating the hardware interrupt to the software level.

The perfect behavior would be one of an exception triggered on the main thread, stopping the robot before it can do any harm.

I have tried many "best practice" ways like event handling, but this leaves a dangerous period where the robot finishes its current mouvement before handling the hardware interrupt event. I also considered Signals although using these for thread communication isn't ideal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To those who might find this later, I avoided the problem by discharging my main thread from all operations that take a long time to accomplish (any text to voice, animation). That way the main thread orders a command, waits for its completion, and while waiting, reads the USB messages. If the hardware interrupt message is received, it kills all threads and goes to an emergency stop mode.